# Openssl1.0.1j .so files for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to build Openssl for android,I followed following link  [Openssl For Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android).This link generates libcrypto.a and libssl.a. Android application requires shared .so(Shared) library to be used in the application.How can generate .so files from above .a library files.Or any link/post that will help me to generate .so files from latest Openssl code.

Comment: You cited the page that gives you everything you need. Why would you ask for an off-site resource (which is off-topic) when you have what you need? You should work through the procedure, and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify original device files and therefore should distribute your own copy of libraries.
The trick which allows to use your own library versions is described in manual which you have already read.  Just look to the section "Using OpenSSL in an Application":

http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Using_OpenSSL_in_an_Application

Example: 
[error when trying to compile wrapper for openssl library libcrypto.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667953/error-when-trying-to-compile-wrapper-for-openssl-library-libcrypto-a)